# Jquery Ajax throw error when calling web api action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

This is my jquery ajax code which i am using to call web api action.

```
var baseurl = 'http://localhost:58782/api/Appointments/UserAppointments/tridip@gmail.com/'

$.ajax({
url: baseurl,
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
}

}).done(function () {


});
```

This is my web api code which return `IEnumerable<Entities.UserAppointments>` by `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage`

Full web API code. It is tested and working. I guess the error is in jquery ajax code.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet, System.Web.Http.Route("UserAppointments/{email}")]
public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage UserAppointments(string email = null)
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage retObject = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        UserAppointmentService _appservice = new UserAppointmentService();
        IEnumerable<Entities.UserAppointments> app = _appservice.GetAllUserAppointments(email);

        if (app.Count() <= 0)
        {
            var message = string.Format("No appointment found for the user [{0}]", email);
            HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
            retObject = Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
            retObject.ReasonPhrase = message;
        }
        else
        {
            retObject = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, app);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var message = string.Format("No email provided");
        HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
        retObject = Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
        retObject.ReasonPhrase = message;

    }
    return retObject;
}

public class UserAppointments
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
    public string AvailableDate { get; set; }
    public string AvailableTime { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

My objective is to capture `IEnumerable<Entities.UserAppointments>` by jquery and iterate in data and append those data in table dynamically.

Please guide me how to do it. thanks

Comment: And what error does `$.ajax` report?

Comment: in console it is showing text error. no error detail comes.

Comment: What information does `errorThrown` hold? And also the Network tab of the developer tools would show you relevant informations like http error code. Is it a ` 4xx`   or a ` 5xx`?

Comment: i capture the error text that is `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58782/api/Appointments/UserAppointments/'.`   this way i capture `                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                            alert(err.Message);
                            console.log(textStatus);
                        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use %40 for @.
As in

```
var baseurl = 'http://localhost:58782/api/Appointments/UserAppointments/tridip@gmail.com/'
```

should be

```
var baseurl = 'http://localhost:58782/api/Appointments/UserAppointments/tridip%40gmail.com/'
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: i saw my web api action is getting called fine with this base url var baseurl = 'http://localhost:58782/api/Appointments/UserAppointments/tridip@gmail.com/' and return data but ajax is throwing error

Comment: i capture the error text that is No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58782/api/Appointments/UserAppointments/'. this way i capture ` error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); alert(err.Message); console.log(textStatus); }`

Comment: how to convert tridip@gmail.com to tridip%40gmail.com programmatically by javascript

Comment: encodeURIComponent is not working  `var baseurl = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"]' + 'api/Appointments/UserAppointments/' + encodeURIComponent(useremail) + '/';
`

Comment: using encodeURIComponent  i am getting this url http://localhost:58782/api/Appointments/UserAppointments// where email is missing and url end with two //

Comment: What are Razor variables and what are JavaScript variables in that statement? Paste the full Razor code

Comment: Better yet, paste the JavaScript that results from the Razor code

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            var useremail = '@User.Identity.Name';
            var baseurl = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"]' + 'api/Appointments/UserAppointments/' + useremail + '/';
}); useremail has value called tridip@gmail.com

Comment: That still looks like a mixture of Razor and JS :) what is the resulting JS?

Comment: this issue sorted with encodeURIComponent . thanks a lot.

Comment: can you tell me how could i iterate in json which return by web api and build table rows.

Comment: Don't understand. think you should ask another question if it is totally different.

Comment: yes asked. here is the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541967/jquery-ajax-how-to-iterate-in-json-and-build-html-table